# Call ExceptionMapper from another ExceptionMapper in JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

In my RESTEasy application I'm getting a `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException`, because a checked exception is being thrown from a method that doesn't declare the exception in the throws clause.
So I'm writing an `UndeclaredThrowableExceptionMapper`. The `UndeclaredThrowableException` wraps the real exception; I call `e.getCause()` to retrieve it.
Can I then throw it or somehow look up the proper `ExceptionMapper` to handle it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try adding a `@Context javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` field/property to your `UndeclaredThrowableExceptionMapper` class.
Then use `Providers.getExceptionMapper(Class)` to look up the real exception mapper you want to use.