# Jersey ExceptionMapper doesn't map exceptions

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jersey, spring-boot

my Spring Boot + Jersey REST service doesn't work as expected.

EmailExistsException is thrown in UserController but I only receive error 500. All the time. And my exceptions aren't logged.

I suspect there is some configuration issue with exception handling but don't know where to set it up. Any suggestions?

```
@POST
@Path("register")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response register(NewUserPayload newUserPayload) throws EmailExistsException, MessagingException
```

EmailExistsExceptionMapper

```
@Provider
public class EmailExistsExceptionMapper extends AbstractExceptionMapper       implements
    ExceptionMapper<EmailExistsException>
{
@Override
public Response toResponse(EmailExistsException e)
{
    ResponseEntity re = new ResponseEntity(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    return this.errorResponse(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST_400, re, e);
}
}
```

AbstractExceptionMapper

```
@Slf4j
public abstract class AbstractExceptionMapper
{
protected Response errorResponse(int status, ResponseEntity responseEntity, Throwable t)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    t.printStackTrace(pw);
    log.error(sw.toString()); // logging stack trace.

    return customizeResponse(status, responseEntity);
}

private Response customizeResponse(int status, ResponseEntity responseEntity)
{
    return Response.status(status).entity(responseEntity).build();
}
}
```

build.gradle

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey"
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer that solved my problems:

I've put packages("package.name"); which is my root package name and exception mappers work like a charm.

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
public JerseyConfig()
{
    packages("package.name");
    register(UserController.class);
    register(TimezoneController.class);
}
}
```

Comment: no information about this configuration in the [jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6653). Does the `package` declaration will avoid you to declare controllers ?

Comment: I've found it in some code snippet on the internet. I'm in Scala now so couldn't tell you more info about it.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out you have to either explicitly `register(YourExceptionMapper.class)` or place it in a scanned package via `packages("YourExceptionMapperPackage")`. I spent couple of hours trying to figure this out before I found your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured custom ExceptionMapper as a jax-rs provider, and Are you sure that your exception is getting wrapped into EmailExistsException? You may have to look at this post.

[JAX-RS using exception mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293599/jax-rs-using-exception-mappers)

Comment: It has a @Provider annotation and yes, I'm sure that it gets wrapped and thrown. Another thing is that when I try to put breakpoint in EmailExistsExceptionMapper it is not alive in IDEA in debug mode. It seems that somehow it isn't used? Some config is missing maybe but where?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I just mentioned the root package on the web.xml file in `<param-value>` tag of `<init-param>`

Then It started working like charm

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.two95.restful</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using ExceptionMapper, you must register your exception mapper:

```
@Component
@Provider
public class ApiApplicationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
       ...
    }
}
```

In Jersey config class, scan Jersey Endpoint class with `@Path` annotation and custom Exception Mapper with `@Provider` annotation to register:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.registerEndpoints();
        this.registerExceptionMappers();
    }

    private void registerEndpoints() {
        Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class);
        for (Object apiClass : beans.values()) {
            logger.info("Jersey register: " + apiClass.getClass().getName());
            register(apiClass);
        }
    }

    private void registerExceptionMappers() {
        Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Provider.class);
        for (Object exceptionMapper : beans.values()) {
            logger.info("Jersey exception mapper register: " + exceptionMapper.getClass().getName());
            register(exceptionMapper);
        }
    }
```