# Jersey ExceptionMapper not working with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I am using jersey with spring boot, and I have a exception mapper:

```
package org.smarter.providers;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.smarter.exception.ApiException;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.smarter.exception.UserException.UNAUTHORIZED;

@Provider
public class ExceptionMapper implements javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<ApiException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ApiException exception) {
        return Response.status(status(exception)).build();
    }

    private Integer status(ApiException exception) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()
                .put(UNAUTHORIZED, 401)
                .build()
                .get(exception.code()))
                .orElse(404);
    }
}
```

Also registered, and using debug, i can see this mapper get invoked correctly, but how ever the final response still returning 404, no matter using junit test or manual test.

Here is the test:

```
when()
                .get("/users/current/memos/daily")
                .then()
                .statusCode(401);
```

And then registered in Jersey Configuration:

`register(ExceptionMapper.class);`

I am using jersey with spring boot, and don't know how to trouble shooting on this. any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey ExceptionMapper doesn't map exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982948/jersey-exceptionmapper-doesnt-map-exceptions)

Comment: @user7294900, I already registered as that post suggested, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597274/jersey-returns-404-with-any-error-status-code

Answer (score 0):

> I can see this mapper gets invoked correctly, but how ever the final response still returning `404`.

It may be an issue with the implementation of your `status()` method. Are you sure `exception.code()` returns `401`?

By the way, do you need such level of complexity using an `Optional` and an `ImmutableMap`? You could use:

```
private Integer status(ApiException exception) {
    if (exception.code() == 401) {
        return exception.code();
    } else {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: the `exception.code()` actually only returns a string which is the my exception code in my application, for example, is the user is unauthorized, it will return `"unauthorized"`, I am tying to build a map between my exception code and http status code, so I use ImmutableMap, which key is the my exception code, and value is the htt p status code, and Optional was used for non-exist mapping. By the way, I can confirm that the exception.code() is returning "UNAUTHORIZED" by evaluate when debugging, and which should correctly map to 401. Thanks for the answer anyway.