# Should a jax-rs based framework use a single exception mapper?

Tags: java, jax-rs

We have a large legacy application to which we recently added jersey/jax-rs based functionality. The idea is that we will implement new functionality for our UI layer as restful APIs. A first prototype is working nicely - but it is lacking proper error handling.

I had a closer look at the initial implementation, and what I found is that there is a "base task" class that registers a specific [ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293599/jax-rs-using-exception-mappers). The idea is that there will be *different* and *disjunct* **sub tasks** extending that base task.

My initial thought was: each *sub task* should have its own, specific exception mapper.

In other words: I see two different options:

- one central exception mapper, that works **all** exceptions thrown within *any* of the numerous sub tasks we are going to implement over time
- one mapper *per* sub task

Option 1 leading to well, one central piece of code - but much less flexible compared to option 2 (it starts with things like: normally our sub tasks have their own "log id" when writing logs - but a central mapper doesn't know about its context and has to use the very same log id all the time).

My question is: are the *hard technical* facts (or well established "best procedures") to select between the two options?

Comment: I think this would be similar setup as with Java exception handlers in general: specialized exception handlers for exception that need to receive special treatment (such as those you mention that need specific context info) or can be recovered from, and one catch-all somewhere else that would report unhandled/unexpected/etc. exceptions, similarly to how `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research resp. design discussions, I realize that basically my *question* goes into the wrong direction:

- first of all, there is no need for a *catching-everything-mapper*. Instead one can extend java.util.logging.Handler to then configure a resource to use a org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature.
- coming from there: ideally, an exception mapper should just do that: map a specific exception to some expected "result".

In other words: our solution boils down to

- using the "logging" capabilities of jersey to log any incoming exception
- having some generic and some "per component" exception mappers

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, one general exception handler to catch everything `public class GenericExceptionMapperProvider implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>`, and, you can continue adding more exception handlers as needed.

> JAX-RS supports exception inheritance as well. When an exception is
>   thrown, JAX-RS will first try to find an ExceptionMapper for that
>   exception’s type. If it cannot find one, it will look for a mapper
>   that can handle the exception’s superclass. It will continue this
>   process until there are no more superclasses to match against.
>   [read more](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd)

Here a post that I wrote: http://blog.nafiux.com/posts/jax-rs-exception-handling/

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought about this for some more time; and decided in the end to put up a self-answer. But again- thank you very much for your helpful input.